# Complex CoreData query

Tags: sorting, core-data, nspredicate

I am very new to CoreData and would like to do something like this.

I have 2 Entities

```
Cave.title            Condition.date
Cave.conditions <-->> Condition.cave
```

I need to query all Conditions and sort it by date. (Latest first)
Then I need to get their cave.title but each cave should show only once (latest conditions)

Example

```
Condition1 (06.09.2011) - Cave1
Condition2 (05.09.2011) - Cave3
Condition3 (05.09.2011) - Cave1
Condition4 (04.09.2011) - Cave5
```

This should show like this

```
Cave1 (06.09.2011)
Cave3 (05.09.2011)
Cave5 (04.09.2011)
```

Any idea on how I could get this done?

In SQL I would do it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.title as title, c.caveID as caveID, cn.countryshort as countryshort, MAX(cc.divedate) as divedate
                FROM caves as c, countries as cn, caveconditions as cc 
                WHERE cn.countryID = c.countryID 
                AND c.caveID = cc.caveID 
                GROUP BY c.title            
                ORDER BY divedate DESC;
```

Output

```
2011-09-08 13:39:24.951 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Chaudanne (1287350157)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.952 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Sorgente Bossi (1287333080)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.953 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Elefante Bianco (1287248755)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.953 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Cogol dei Siori - Oliero (1287248678)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.954 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Source du Lison (1287324493)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.955 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Resurgénce de Gouron (1287324296)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.955 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Fontaine du Truffe (1287006107)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.956 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Gouffre de Cabouy (1287005780)
2011-09-08 13:39:24.957 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Emergence du Ressel (1286908470)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.037 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Source de l'Orbe (1287175659)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.120 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Bätterich (1286812411)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.220 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Cogol dei Siori - Oliero (1286787535)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.288 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Fontaine de Saint Georges (1286744641)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.379 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Source du Doubs (1286736293)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.480 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Source Bleue (Montperreux) (1286736150)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.613 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Source Bleue Cusance (1286814108)
2011-09-08 13:39:26.796 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Fontaine de Saint Georges (1286652629)
2011-09-08 13:39:27.096 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Source de l'Orbe (1286735940)
2011-09-08 13:39:27.846 CaveConditions[23026:11903] Gouffre de Cabouy (1286568932)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch once to get all the conditions sorted by date and then do some logic to filter the fetched data to get the titles.

If you need to see some code let me know.

Edit: OK let me try..

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[fetch setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Condition" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetch setEntity:entity];

[fetch setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"cave.title"];

NSError *error;
[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

[fetch release];
[sort release];
```

I'm not sure haven't tried it myself, but I think this should work. Let me know how it goes..

Comment: I am pretty sure this can be pulled out directly at once. I have edited my previous post and added the SQL code I would run if it was in an SQL DB.

Comment: If it doesn't work try for the setPropertiesToFetch the following:

[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"nameOfRelationship.title"];

('nameOfRelationship' being the name of the relationship from Condition to Cave, not the other way around)

Comment: I edited my last post and added the console output. It does show the list but the cave names are shown more than once.. it should only show the top ones of each cave.

Comment: what is the number in the brackets after the cave names? And are you sure you did set [fetch setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; ?

Comment: hmm that's a little odd.. so everything works except that names show up multiple times instead of just the one with the oldest date from each name?

Comment: exactly. Somehow it has to be grouped or so

Comment: hmmm.. I haven't used "DistinctResults" myself yet.. I guess I will have to look further into it.. but that has to wait until tomorrow.. sorry :)

Comment: can you show me your code where you create the fetch request and then execute it?

Comment: Ist it maybe a problem because I am using a nsfetchedreusltscontroller? (Not at home at the moment. So can't get the code yet)

Comment: Depends.. why are you using a NSFRC? Is the data displayed in a UITableView? Let me know when you posted the code. I'll try my best :)

Comment: Yes it is displayed in a TableView

Comment: *bump* are you still trying to figure this out?

Comment: I used a different way to display it so it is not realy needed anymore. Still it would be interesting to know I think.

Comment: well if setReturnDistinctResults:YES works, then my code from above would work totally fine, I don't know if it's a bug from xcode, and I'm too busy myself with other projects to try it out.. sorry.. maybe I'll get around to it some time ..

Comment: Did you try [fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"nameOfRelationship.title"]; ?